# chef-solo not applying recipe changes

Tags: docker, chef-infra

I'm trying to `vagrant up`, edit `..\default.rb` then run `sudo chef-solo` and have my new recipe version be run by chef.

This is not working for me.
After my initial vagrant run, chef does not apply updates to recipes.

I can modify `..\default.rb` all I want, but chef-solo runs the original version.

## vagrant setup script

```
[ ! -d /etc/chef ] && mkdir /etc/chef
[ ! -f /etc/chef/solo.rb ] && ln -s /vagrant/chef/config/solo.rb /etc/chef/solo.rb
[ ! -d /etc/chef/cookbooks ] && ln -s /vagrant/chef/cookbooks  /etc/chef/cookbooks
cd /vagrant/chef/cookbooks/jenkins && berks vendor /etc/chef/vendor-cookbooks
cd /vagrant/chef/nodes && cp jenkins.json /tmp/jenkins.json
chef-solo --json-attributes /tmp/jenkins.json
```

## /etc/chef/solo.rb

```
cookbooks_path %w(/etc/chef/vendor-cookbooks /etc/chef/cookbooks)
json_attribs '/tmp/jenkins.json'
```

## jenkins.json

```
{
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[jenkins::default]"
  ]
}
```

## chef/cookbooks/jenkins/recipes/default.rb

```
docker_image 'jenkins-data' do
  source 'docker/jenkins-data/Dockerfile'
  action :build
end
```

*Edit:* I'm currently trying to use test-kitchen to solve this.

Comment: If you update the cookbook out of the vm, how do you expect the vm to know the change ?

Comment: @Tensibai I'm using vagrant. `/vagrant` is a synced folder and my cookbook is being synced.

Comment: As far as I remember synced folders are synced/updated as part of vagrant up and vagrant provision not magically at each change, but I may be wrong

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders && https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/

Comment: In this case I assume your problem comes from the `berks vendor`, as you're not sharing a real workflow of what you're doing, it's hard to guess if you call berks vendor again or not after your modification, according to your code, you have a "vendored" version of the cookbook in the first cookbook path, and you're modifying the version in the second one. If you modify a cookbook, update it's metadata.rb, this will also enforce chef to update it's own cache.